# Create a list of lists from a string in Python

Tags: python, string, list, split

I have a string that looks like this:

```
str = "[abc,7.56],[dfe,2.44],[iij,2.31]"
```

and I want it to be a list of lists:

```
ls = [["abc",7.56],["dfe",2.44],["iij",2.31]]
```

I tried to use `list(str.split(","))` but then it split both inside- and between the lists. Also, the list would then contain six elements (which are not lists) rather than three. How should I proceed?

Comment: Your expected result is invalid code, and the input also isn't valid code. If it was valid in some common format, you could try to load it as JSON or `ast.literal_eval`. But as is, you'd have to invent your own parser, and for that we'd need to know more about the possible edge cases. … Does it *have* to be this particular input format?

Comment: I have updated the code so that the expected result is valid.

Comment: OK, one down… now, again, does it have to be this particular input format?

Comment: Yes, it has to be this particular input format. Thank you.

Comment: Can you *define* this particular input format more? Are there any edge cases to consider like special characters? Or will it always match the regex `\[([a-z]+),(\d+\.\d+)\]` (hint hint…)?

Comment: No special cases, the first item inside each list is string with letters (of same length) and second part is a number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the pattern is not wildly changing as asked in the comments, there are three steps:

1. find content of each list via a regex
2. split the content over `,`
3. convert the second elements to numbers

```py
import re

s = "[abc,7.56],[dfe,2.44],[iij,2.31]"
list_contents = re.findall(r"\[(.+?)\]", s)  # non-greedily take what are between [..]
split_as_strings = [content.split(",") for content in list_contents]
result = [[pair[0], float(pair[1])] for pair in split_as_strings]
```

`result` would be

```
[['abc', 7.56], ['dfe', 2.44], ['iij', 2.31]]
```

and intermediate results:

```
list_contents == ['abc,7.56', 'dfe,2.44', 'iij,2.31']

split_as_strings == [['abc', '7.56'], ['dfe', '2.44'], ['iij', '2.31']]
```

Comment: Thank you. Indeed, the pattern is not changing. I did suspect regex might be useful.

Answer (score 0):

What you're doing is parsing.  This is not trivial at all: lots of edge cases etc...

Your input does look like some dialect of JSON, a very known data format, that could be parsed like so:

```py
ls = json.loads('[["a", 1], ["b", 2]]')
assert ls == [["a", 1], ["b", 2]]
```

If need be, don't be tempted to build your own parser, rather take a look at parsing libraries like enumerated in https://tomassetti.me/parsing-in-python/.

Comment: Also, I had some good experiences with https://fdik.org/pyPEG/

Answer (score -2):

If you want list of list then use `append`:

```
listoflists = []
listoflists.append(str)
```